# Build Fails When Running React-Native App For Android, @react-native-async-storage:extractReleaseAnnotations

Tags: android, react-native

Running into a permissions error with package @react-native-async-storage. Running `./gradlew clean` outputs..

> Task :@react-native-async-storage:clean FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':@react-native-async-storage:clean'.
>   java.io.IOException: Unable to delete directory 'REDACTED-PATH/node_modules/@react-native-async-storage/async-storage/android/build'
>   Failed to delete some children. This might happen because a process has files open or has its working directory set in the target
>   directory.

When running `react-native run-android` the output is this..

> Task :@react-native-async-storage:checkDebugManifest FAILED
>
> Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it
> incompatible with Gradle 7.0. Use '--warning-mode all' to show the
> individual deprecation warnings. See
> https://docs.gradle.org/6.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
> 1 actionable task: 1 executed
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':@react-native-async-storage:checkDebugManifest'.
>   Failed to create parent directory 'REDACTED-PATH/node_modules/@react-native-async-storage/async-storage/android/build/intermediates/check_manifest_result/debug'

For information..

```
ext {
        // buildToolsVersion = "27.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 29
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    }
```

If you need more information please let me know.. I've been having this issue for a long time now.